# How to test a custom class (PSR-4 autoloaded) using model functions, with PHPUnit in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I was writing a custom class to handle some unique operations in my project, which is developed in Laravel 5.2. In that, I've called some existing model functions also to fetch some values from the database. If we run the code, it'll work fine. But when I wrote different test cases and tested those classes alone, a database connection error has occurred, as the connection was not established.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function connection() on null in /var/www/html/****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 3314

I could write a separate test code to create and delete resources in the database. But that is not what I'm searching for. I wanted to use custom functions written in the model class like shown below.

```
<?php
namespace ****\Paymentmethod;

use App\Models\Customer;
/**
* ****** Package - Additional helpers
* @package *******
* @author ********
* 
* Card is intended to handle the operations related to credit cards
*
*/
class Card
{
    private $var;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //constructor
    }

    public static function getCard($user_id)
    {
        return Customer::getCustomerInfo($user_id);
    }
}
```

This `Card` class is used in another class and that is what I'm testing.
`Customer` is a model class and `getCustomerInfo` is a custom method in it.

Comment: @tam5: it is not instantiated, that is correct. But can you explain or get me a resource on how to extend the testcase laravel provides

Comment: @tam5: Got it, thanks a lot. I just need to extend the TestCase of laravel, that's all. Please write it as an answer, I'll approve it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're app instance is probably not instantiated.

Have a look at the `TestCase.php` that Laravel provides in the `tests/` folder, it creates an instance of the app. Unless your test is a pure 'unit' test which does not rely on the framework at all, you need to make sure your test `extends` the `TestCase` class so that it too will instantiate an application instance.

The reason it works when you run outside of the tests is when you enter the application via a route or a console command, the application is bootstrapped for you.